# org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security, servlet-filters, sitemesh

I have a maven webapp based on spring framework 3 and when I run the application on jetty using `maven-jetty-plugin` by running the command `mvn -e clean jetty:run` it runs alright, but when I run it on tomcat using `tomcat-maven-plugin` by running the command `mvn -e clean tomcat:run` it gives me the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Following is how I've got filters in the `web.xml` are configured:

```
<!-- Filters -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>methodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>methodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Could someone help me understand why am I getting this error and help me resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041761/first-confluence-servlet-plugin-classcastexception-problem

Comment: @axtavt I just checked and `<scope>provided</scope>` was commented out as `<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
   </dependency>` in the `pom.xml` of the appplication. And when I uncommented the `<scope>provided</scope>` the java source code started having compile errors for `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` and other classes from `javax.servlet.http` could not be imported anymore. I never had compiling issues with `scope` being set as `provided`.

Comment: @axtavt But should jetty also not be complaining if `scope` being set to anything other than `provided` for artifact `com.springsource.javax.servlet` was the issue?

Answer (score 3):

1. first see [First confluence servlet plugin, ClassCastException problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041761/first-confluence-servlet-plugin-classcastexception-problem)

> ```
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
>    <version>2.5</version>
>    <scope>provided</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

notice that

> ```
> <scope>provided</scope>
> ```

then you need check the dependency tree, exclude other servlet-api